# img header on mobile pushes down text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to edit my wordpress theme. I changed the header h1 to an img to display the logo. It looks fine on computer, but on mobile, it's doing something weird so that the background image shows through between the logo and the navbar.

You can view here: http://www.juicecrawl.com/blog

Any ideas on how to scale the logo image so it works for both computer & mobile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that small resolution, your css is shrinking the background image size to fit on the screen. You either want to set background-size to 'cover' in the header area or set the background-image to 'none' to get rid of it for mobile.
You also want to make your logo responsive. to do this firstly remove the height="100px" from the "img" and use css instead.

```
/*set height of the image to 100px*/
.site-header h1 img {height:100px;}
/*for mobile, set background-size to cover and set the logo to have a max width of 100% so that it fits on the screen*/
@media (max-width: 359px) {
  .site-header {
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .site-header h1 img {max-width:100%;height:auto}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a theme-child .css to make edits, and when I copy this code into the child css, it doesn't seem to override the theme settings. I'm not seeing a change.

Comment: Ok i can see it in your "twentythirteen-child/style.css" file. Problem is it is being overwritten by some other css just before your closing </head> tag.

Comment: For now, until you figure out how to edit that css just before your closing </head> tag, use "!important" on your css. eg .site-header h1 img {max-width:100% !important;height:auto !important}

Comment: Thank you! I found the css inside an extra header.php and removed it. The reason for using a child theme is to prevent unknown changes. Do you think an update will cause for this to be removed again? The !important still didn't override so I thought the best to do was remove.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `background-size` of `.site-header` in the media query to `cover` instead of `768px auto`.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .site-header {
     // background-size: 768px auto;
     background-size: cover;
 }
}
```